# Failed to notify project evaluation listener :Library/java/javavirtual machines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/contents/home

Tags: java, android-studio

Facing failed to notify project evaluation listener error in Android studio in Mac.

Library/java/javavirtual machines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/contents/home

Tried Run a project in Android studio in Mac

Tried updating to latest version of Android studio

Tried setting up java path in Environment variable.